# R: Subtract rows from the first row in each group

Tags: r, dplyr, subtraction

I would like to subtract each rows from the first row in each Group for the column Distance.

My data is the following:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Distance = c(0.05, 0.084, 0.06, 0.03, 
0.034, 0.0534, 0.034, 0.23, 0.34, 0.6435, 0.6346, 0.234, 0.246, 
0.4, 0.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

I have tried the following code:

```
Data <- Data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Difference=Distance - dplyr:: lag(Distance))
```

However, how can I adjust the code so that for each Group the value in column Distance is subtracted from the value in the first row for each group?
So for group 1 it would mean that the values 0.084, 0.06, 0.03 and 0.034 are all subtracted from 0.05.

Comment: `Difference = Distance[1] - Distance` or `Difference = first(Distance) - Distance` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: see comments:**
Many thanks to @Gregor Thomas:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Distance = Distance - Distance[1])
```

Ok now I see it also. It is the same solution as Gregor Thomas provided in the comments just in `dplyr` way!

```
Group Distance
   <int>    <dbl>
 1     1   0     
 2     1   0.034 
 3     1   0.0100
 4     1  -0.02  
 5     1  -0.016 
 6     2   0     
 7     2  -0.0194
 8     2   0.177 
 9     2   0.287 
10     2   0.590 
11     3   0     
12     3  -0.401 
13     3  -0.389 
14     3  -0.235 
15     3   0.0654
```

**First answer:**
Here is another `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Distance = Distance - Distance[row_number() == 1])
```

```
   Group Distance
   <int>    <dbl>
 1     1   0     
 2     1   0.034 
 3     1   0.0100
 4     1  -0.02  
 5     1  -0.016 
 6     2   0     
 7     2  -0.0194
 8     2   0.177 
 9     2   0.287 
10     2   0.590 
11     3   0     
12     3  -0.401 
13     3  -0.389 
14     3  -0.235 
15     3   0.0654
```

Comment: `[row_number() == 1]` seems like a long way to write `[1]` ;)

Comment: lol. Ok just realized now. Clear. Many thanks. I will update!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Distance2 = first(Distance) - Distance) %>% 
  ungroup

#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    Group Distance Distance2
#>    <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1     1   0.05      0     
#>  2     1   0.084    -0.034 
#>  3     1   0.06     -0.0100
#>  4     1   0.03      0.02  
#>  5     1   0.034     0.016 
#>  6     2   0.0534    0     
#>  7     2   0.034     0.0194
#>  8     2   0.23     -0.177 
#>  9     2   0.34     -0.287 
#> 10     2   0.644    -0.590 
#> 11     3   0.635     0     
#> 12     3   0.234     0.401 
#> 13     3   0.246     0.389 
#> 14     3   0.4       0.235 
#> 15     3   0.7      -0.0654
```